# Can zustand be used in backend projects? Or is it only suited for frontend applications?

Tags: zustand

I am using Nest JS for backend development and I have some global variables that need to be stored throughout the app. My first choice was redux but these variables aren't very big and complicated so I was planning to try zustand with it.

Can zustand be used with a backend application or it relies a lot on frontend hooks for optimization use cases?

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly for frontend development only. There are options to use it with SSR, for instance [official example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-zustand).

I see the react state management on the server side a bit tricky, especially having the horizontal scaling/load-balancer - the is no guarantee that the next request from the FE goes to the same instance of the application, so the better approach is to implement server-side as a set of stateless function, passing everything in the request. One of the results for ["Stateless REST API"](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) with a short explanation.